# How to update Bootstrap v3.3.7 to v4.0.0 beta2 in Asp.net core 2.0 mvc project?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, bootstrap-4, asp.net-core-2.0

I am wondering what is the process to update Bootstrap v3.3.7 to v.4.0.0 beta-2 in Asp.net core 2.0 mvc project.

[image]

Comment: one of the steps is to read migration instructions from bootstrap 3 to v4: 
 https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/

Comment: Beside the actual updating the Bootstrap from 3 to 4 (using bower, etc), you need to manually change all the Bootstrap 3 features/usage to 4. For example, this `<li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>` is changed to `<li class="nav-item">@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home", null, htmlAttributes: new Dictionary<string, object> { { "class", "nav-link" } })</li>`

Answer (score 2):

follow steps for bootstrap 4.0.0 beta.3 version. Most probably for other versions also will work.

1. Open Node.js Console
2. Cd Path to your project where `package.json` is located
3. run command `npm install popper.js --save`
4. run command `npm install bootstrap@4.0.0-beta.3`
5. `webpack --config webpack.config.vendor.js` - update vendor.js and vendor.css files.
6. rebuild project and test it. If it will not work also run `Install-Package bootstrap -Pre` in VS Package Manager Console.

Be prepared that styles will not work anymore. And project will not launch due huge changes in bootstrap.

Hope it will help.