# How to use Bootstrap 4 in ASP.NET Core

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, nuget, bootstrap-4, asp.net-core-2.0

I want to update Bootstrap in ASP.NET Core with NuGet. I used this:

```
Install-Package bootstrap -Version 4.0.0
```

It did add the dependencies but how do I add it to my project now? What is the path for local NuGet dependencies?

[image: Installed NuGet dependencies]

Comment: BS4 shouldn't have Bower support (source: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/#breaking)

Comment: Replace bootstrap@4.0.0-beta.3 with bootstrap@4.0.0: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47985337/how-to-update-bootstrap-v3-3-7-to-v4-0-0-beta2-in-asp-net-core-2-0-mvc-project#comment83217849_47985337

Comment: Currently this should be the accepted answer, the easiest using Libman: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53012140/578552

Comment: Version 4.4.1 compatible now by NUGET.

Comment: After 2019, It is better to use **LibMan** as explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59606174/1129978) post.

Answer (score 244, accepted):

As others already mentioned, the package manager [Bower](https://bower.io/), that was usually used for dependencies like this in application that do not rely on heavy client-side scripting, is [on the way out](https://github.com/bower/bower/issues/2298) and actively recommending to move to other solutions:

> ..psst! While Bower is maintained, we recommend [yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/) and [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) for new front-end projects!

So although you can still use it right now, Bootstrap has also announced to [drop support for it](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/#breaking). As a result, the built-in ASP.NET Core templates are slowly being edited to move away from it too.

Unfortunately, there is no clear path forward. This is mostly due to the fact that web applications are continuously moving further into the client-side, requiring complex client-side build systems and many dependencies. So if you are building something like that, you might already know how to solve this then, and you can expand your existing build process to simply also include Bootstrap and jQuery there.

But there are still many web applications out there that are not that heavy on the client-side, where the application still runs mainly on the server and the server serves static views as a result. Bower previously filled this by making it easy to just publish client-side dependencies without that much of a process.

In the .NET world we also have NuGet and with previous ASP.NET versions, we could use NuGet as well to add dependencies to some client-side dependencies since NuGet would just place the content into our project correctly. Unfortunately, with the new `.csproj` format and the new NuGet, installed packages are located outside of our project, so we cannot simply reference those.

This leaves us with a few options how to add our dependencies:

### One-time installation

This is what the ASP.NET Core templates, that are not single-page applications, are currently doing. When you use those to create a new application, the `wwwroot` folder simply contains a folder `lib` that contains the dependencies:

[image: wwwroot folder contains lib folder with static dependencies]

If you look closely at the files currently, you can see that they were originally placed there with Bower to create the template, but that is likely to change soon. The basic idea is that the files are copied **once** to the `wwwroot` folder so you can depend on them.

To do this, we can simply follow Bootstrap’s introduction and [download the compiled files](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/download/) directly. As mentioned on the download site, this does not include [jQuery](https://jquery.com/), so we need to download that separately too; it [does  contain](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/contents/) [Popper.js](https://popper.js.org/) though if we choose to use the `bootstrap.bundle` file later—which we will do. For jQuery, we can simply get a single “compressed, production” file from [the download site](https://jquery.com/download/) (right-click the link and select "Save link as..." from the menu).

This leaves us with a few files which will simply extract and copy into the `wwwroot` folder. We can also make a `lib` folder to make it clearer that these are external dependencies:

[image: wwwroot folder contains lib folder with our installed dependencies]

That’s all we need, so now we just need to adjust our `_Layout.cshtml` file to include those dependencies. For that, we add the following block to the `<head>`:

```
<environment include="Development">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/css/bootstrap.css" />
</environment>
<environment exclude="Development">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
</environment>
```

And the following block at the very end of the `<body>`:

```
<environment include="Development">
    <script src="~/lib/js/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/js/bootstrap.bundle.js"></script>
</environment>
<environment exclude="Development">
    <script src="~/lib/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</environment>
```

You can also just include the minified versions and skip the `<environment>` tag helpers here to make it a bit simpler. But that’s all you need to do to keep you starting.

### Dependencies from NPM

The more modern way, also if you want to keep your dependencies updated, would be to get the dependencies from the NPM package repository. You can use either NPM or Yarn for this; in my example, I’ll use NPM.

To start off, we need to create a `package.json` file for our project, so we can specify our dependencies. To do this, we simply do that from the “Add New Item” dialog:

[image: Add New Item: npm Configuration file]

Once we have that, we need to edit it to include our dependencies. It should something look like this:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "name": "asp.net",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "4.0.0",
    "jquery": "3.3.1",
    "popper.js": "1.12.9"
  }
}
```

By saving, Visual Studio will already run NPM to install the dependencies for us. They will be installed into the `node_modules` folder. So what is left to do is to get the files from there into our `wwwroot` folder. There are a few options to do that:

#### `bundleconfig.json` for bundling and minification

We can use one of the various ways to consume a `bundleconfig.json` for bundling and minification, as explained in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/bundling-and-minification). A very easy way is to simply use the [BuildBundlerMinifier NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BuildBundlerMinifier/) which automatically sets up a build task for this.

After installing that package, we need to create a `bundleconfig.json` at the root of the project with the following contents:

```
[
  {
    "outputFileName": "wwwroot/vendor.min.css",
    "inputFiles": [
      "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    ],
    "minify": { "enabled": false }
  },
  {
    "outputFileName": "wwwroot/vendor.min.js",
    "inputFiles": [
      "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
      "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
      "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    ],
    "minify": { "enabled": false }
  }
]
```

This basically configures which files to combine into what. And when we build, we can see that the `vendor.min.css` and `vendor.js.css` are created correctly. So all we need to do is to adjust our `_Layouts.html` again to include those files:

```
<!-- inside <head> -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/vendor.min.css" />

<!-- at the end of <body> -->
<script src="~/vendor.min.js"></script>
```

#### Using a task manager like Gulp

If we want to move a bit more into client-side development, we can also start to use tools that we would use there. For example [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) which is a very commonly used build tool for really everything. But we can also start with a simpler task manager like [Gulp](https://gulpjs.com/) and do the few necessary steps ourselves.

For that, we add a `gulpfile.js` into our project root, with the following contents:

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const concat = require('gulp-concat');

const vendorStyles = [
    "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
];
const vendorScripts = [
    "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
    "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
    "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
];

gulp.task('build-vendor-css', () => {
    return gulp.src(vendorStyles)
        .pipe(concat('vendor.min.css'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('wwwroot'));
});

gulp.task('build-vendor-js', () => {
    return gulp.src(vendorScripts)
        .pipe(concat('vendor.min.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('wwwroot'));
});

gulp.task('build-vendor', gulp.parallel('build-vendor-css', 'build-vendor-js'));

gulp.task('default', gulp.series('build-vendor'));
```

Now, we also need to adjust our `package.json` to have dependencies on `gulp` and `gulp-concat`:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "name": "asp.net",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "4.0.0",
    "gulp": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.1",
    "jquery": "3.3.1",
    "popper.js": "1.12.9"
  }
}
```

Finally, we edit our `.csproj` to add the following task which makes sure that our Gulp task runs when we build the project:

```
<Target Name="RunGulp" BeforeTargets="Build">
  <Exec Command="node_modules\.bin\gulp.cmd" />
</Target>
```

Now, when we build, the `default` Gulp task runs, which runs the `build-vendor` tasks, which then builds our `vendor.min.css` and `vendor.min.js` just like we did before. So after adjusting our `_Layout.cshtml` just like above, we can make use of jQuery and Bootstrap.

While the initial setup of Gulp is a bit more complicated than the `bundleconfig.json` one above, we have now have entered the Node-world and can start to make use of all the other cool tools there. So it might be worth to start with this.

### Conclusion

While this suddenly got a lot more complicated than with just using Bower, we also do gain a lot of control with those new options. For example, we can now decide what files are actually included within the `wwwroot` folder and how those exactly look like. And we also can use this to make the first moves into the client-side development world with Node which at least should help *a bit* with the learning curve.

Comment: When using the npm method, I was getting back errors like "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token export".  To fix this I switched to the popper.js umd file "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js".  Otherwise one of the best answers I have ever seen on stack, thank you.

Comment: @JamesBlake Thank you for the feedback! – Let me check about that error, are you using the Gulp-based solution, or the bundleconfig-one?

Comment: That was using bundleconfig.json.

Comment: @JamesBlake Oh, yes, you’re right! The path I had in the answer is an ES6 module compatible file. Fixed it in the answer, thank you! :)

Comment: I am receiving an error following these instructions: "The command "node_modules\.bin\gulp.cmd" exited with code 1."

The output shows:
gulp.task('build-vendor-css', () => {                                
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ) 

(The output points to the closing parenthesis).

Suggestions?

Comment: @user That sounds as if you are using a very old version of Node. You can see the version by running `node -v`, and get a current version [over here on nodejs.org](https://nodejs.org/en/)

Comment: Thanks, this post was super helpful.  Any idea how to get Visual Studio's autocomplete to recognize the newer version of bootstrap?  It seems like mine is still pointing to the old 3.3.7 version

Comment: @dave317 Hmm, I don’t think there is an explicit autocomplete for Bootstrap. I think it’s rather that the Razor toolls will autocomplete CSS classes from .css files. So if you have the bootstrap.css included properly, that should work out of the box.

Comment: SCRATCH THAT, VS autocomplete working great.  Thanks again for this answer.  Super helpful

Comment: Do you have any recommendations as for what files a person can remove in their project and anything in the _Layout that could be removed.

Comment: @dave317 You mean from the default template? You pretty much have full control over that. You need the layouts file and may want to keep the `_ViewStart` and `_ViewImports` to keep MVC working nicely but apart from that, you can do whatever you want. I usually replace the whole layout with my own stuff and completely replace everything that’s inside `wwwroot`. I also remove the `<environment>` switches from the layout since I usually don’t work on projects that take advantage over different sources for these files. I just host my files in the `wwwroot` directly.

Comment: Thanks @poke, makes sense.  I'll try that with a new project and build my own template.

Comment: LOL. I have to laugh or I'll cry. Seventeen years of .Net development using the tooling support of Visual Studio, and it has come to this? Personally, I fail to see how this is forward progress. If it takes this much work just to add Bootstrap styling to a web project then something has gone drastically wrong.

Comment: @camainc If anything, then blame it on the development of the JavaScript ecosystem. This is really not related to .NET or Visual Studio at all. The simple solution is still to just download the files manually and then add them to your web root. That’s just how it worked all the years before too. – And for what it’s worth, Microsoft is working on new VS tooling to make this process simpler (and updatable).

Comment: @poke Thanks for this post, really helpful. I tried both bundleconfig and GULP methods, and everything got added to my project folder as you specified. But i didn't get intellisense working for bootstrap. So I tried the old method, Onetime Installation, download and simply copy files to the lib folder under wwwroot. And I got intellisense working for bootstrap then. So I just wonder, why other methods - GULP and bundleconfig - missing intellisense even if the files got installed properly.

Comment: @SJPadikkoth I think Visual Studio picks up CSS classes automatically from all files that are within the `wwwroot` folder. So it’s possible that Visual Studio does not pick up the files when they are automatically placed there during build. Did you try running the scripts (to have the files being moved there), and then restarting Visual Studio?

Comment: @poke thanks for the reply.But I didn't understand what did you mean by running the scripts (to have the files being moved there)? Could you explain me how can I do the same please. Really appreciate your help.

Comment: @SJPadikkoth I mean, if you are using e.g. the Gulp solution, then make sure to run it once so that the files get created within the `wwwroot` folder. And then check if restarting Visual Studio is enough to make it pick up the CSS rules.

Comment: @poke, thank you for your reply. Yes I did both, ran the scripts and restarted VS. All files got created within wwwroot folder. But still no luck. :(

Comment: @SJPadikkoth I’ve been playing around with this a bit now; unfortunately, Visual Studio behaves really inconsistent there. I *believe* VS will not look into `.min.css` files for this. So if you change the `gulpfile.js` (or the `bundleconfig.json`) to create a `vendor.css` (instead of `vendor.min.css`), then it *should* work. Restarting Visual Studio might still be necessary though.

Comment: @poke Great !!!! It worked very well. changed both `vendor.min.js` and `vendor.min.css` to `vendor.js` and `vendor.css`.  Restarting VS is not necessary actually, just rebuild the solution. Thank you very much.

Comment: Mine was in the "Scripts" section.

Comment: I didn't think there was anything wrong with NuGet and Bower for dependency management? All of this leaves me a bit baffled as to how this is an improvement.

Comment: @Patrick I don’t consider this an improvement. It’s just a very different situation with both NuGet and Bower gone for this type of dependencies.

Comment: Yes I agree with poke @camainc this is not a .net problem. Its the way software development is going. JS everywhere. If you have been developing for 17 years, you can probably continue to do so (as I hope I will be able to) but JS is definitely the way forward.

Comment: @ozzy432836, I know it is not a bootstrap problem, and I never said it was. It is a general development issue with everyone seemingly chasing the next new framework. I've seen a lot of changes in my career, but nothing like what has happened in the last couple of years surrounding Javascript. It has been absolutely nuts watching the development community churning one new framework after another. As for whether JS is the way forward, the jury is still out on that one, especially with WASM and projects like Blazor on the horizon.

Comment: Get me out of here! I want basic GridViews and ASP.Net... client just wants a simple data entry screen and I have to jump all these hurdles now?! @camainc I totally concur

Comment: The new templates with VS 2019 have finally addressed this problem. I know not everyone is able to use the bleeding edge tools though. If so, the easiest thing to do is download BS 4 and add it to the project manually. LibMan us also a good tool to use.

Comment: For projects which wasn't created using the VS's templates **app.UseStaticFiles()** has to be added to "Configure" method in Startup.cs in order to be able to link files located in **wwwroot** folder.

Comment: @camainc, Well, you will continue crying for the foreseeable future. Many of these newfangled tools and languages are developed by folks who lack expertise in software engineering . Most only know HTML/CSS/JS. Consequently, they are able to circumvent a lot of the vetting process real software engineers endure. Also, many of them weren't alive during 1984 revolution when the GUI made computers usable to millions. Command line interfaces are a great way of impressing those who fund these flyby-night web technologies.

Comment: After 2019, It is better to use **LibMan** as explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59606174/1129978) post.

Comment: @HimalayaGarg I wouldn’t say _better_ since it is always good to have multiple options. For example, dependending on your requirements, you may want to establish an npm-based process in order to integrate other Node-based build processes. – But yeah, LibMan is a very good alternative here, as also mentioned in the answer below by SunsetQuest.

Comment: "just simply download them" yeah ok, sure, simple, easy, normal, but now we're depending on nuget for things like ASP and Newtonsoft.JSON, and then fracturing this workflow for what, the inability to copy from the nuget folder on compile/publish because... why... "the basic idea" that they're copied to the wwwroot folder once and THEN you can depend on them? OK but aren't we entirely omitting the rationale behind the intentional pattern breaking disfunction?   The "exactly as you want it" philosophy sucks as it's not worth adopting because it requires breaking symmetry.  Everything is half-ass

Answer (score 65):

Looking into this, it seems like the LibMan approach works best for my needs with adding Bootstrap. I like it because it is now built into Visual Studio 2017(15.8 or later) and has its own dialog boxes.

**Update 6/11/2020:** bootstrap 4.1.3 is now added by default with VS-2019.5 (Thanks to Harald S. Hanssen for noticing.)

The default method VS adds to projects uses Bower but it looks like it is on the way out. In the header of Microsofts [bower](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/bower?view=aspnetcore-2.1) page they write:
[image: Bower is maintained only.Recommend using LibManager]

Following a couple links lead to [Use LibMan with ASP.NET Core in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/libman/libman-vs?view=aspnetcore-2.1) where it [shows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/libman/libman-vs?view=aspnetcore-2.1#use-the-add-client-side-library-dialog) how libs can be added using a built-in Dialog:

> In Solution Explorer, right-click the project folder in which the
>   files should be added. Choose Add > Client-Side Library. The Add
>   Client-Side Library dialog appears: [source: [Scott Addie 2018](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/libman/libman-vs?view=aspnetcore-2.1#use-the-add-client-side-library-dialog)]

[image]

Then for bootstrap just (1) select the unpkg, (2) type in "bootstrap@.." (3) Install. After this, you would just want to verify all the includes in the _Layout.cshtml or other places are correct. They should be something like **href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap..."**)

Comment: I have VS 4.7.02558 (Community Edition) and this was the easiest option for me. I used it in practice projects created to study for the MS 70-486 (MVC) exam, so I can't answer for how effective this is for projects that are headed for production.

Comment: For me, this also was the easiest way to install the stuff with the MS STANDARD TOOL. With the hints in your posting - change Provider to unpkg, type in bootstrap@4., I was able to install. Libman is really not intuitive (in my case, I had also to enter the . (point) after 4, before the packages were showed  (I thought, libman is not working in my environment).

Comment: Just a reminder: if you looking for Bootstrap on CdnJS, be aware is the name is twitter-bootstrap as it was originally called.

Comment: In Visual Studio 2019 (the latest by 11th of June 2020) - The libman file gets created, but I don't see the libman popup window.

Comment: @HaraldS.Hanssen - I just tried it and you are right - bootstrap 4.1.3 is added by default now for new projects. Nice!

Comment: I’ve tested LibMan on several projects and it is really the way to go. Too bad the GUI doesn’t work, but after a few tries it’s easy to use.

Answer (score 20):

Try [Libman](https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/library-manager-libman-visual-studio-2017), it's as simple as Bower and you can specify wwwroot/lib/ as the download folder.

Comment: Not in the release of VS2017 yet: UPDATE: 24-May-2018 – It looks like LibMan didn’t make it into the final release of 15.7. It’s in the preview for 15.8.x

Comment: Looks like this is out now with the final 15.8 release.

Comment: It is available now in VS2017 V 15.8 and much simpler approach than the accepted answer

Answer (score 12):

What does the trick for me is:

1) Right click on wwwroot > Add > Client Side Library

2) Typed "bootstrap" on the search box

3) Select "Choose specific files"

4) Scroll down and select a folder.  In my case I chose "twitter-bootstrap"

5) Check "css" and "js"

6) Click "Install".

A few seconds later I have all of them wwwroot folder. Do the same for all client side packages that you want to add.

Answer (score 8):

Libman seems to be the tool preferred by Microsoft now. It is integrated in Visual Studio 2017(15.8).

[This article](https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/library-manager-libman-visual-studio-2017) describes how to use it and even how to set up a restore performed by the build process.

[Bootstrap's documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/getting-started/contents/#css-files) tells you what files you need in your project.

The following example should work as a configuration for libman.json.

```
{
  "version": "1.0",
  "defaultProvider": "cdnjs",
  "libraries": [
  {
    "library": "twitter-bootstrap@4.2.1",
    "destination": "wwwroot/lib/bootstrap",
    "files": [
    "js/bootstrap.bundle.js",
    "css/bootstrap.min.css"
    ]
  },
  {
    "library": "jquery@3.3.1",
    "destination": "wwwroot/lib/jquery",
    "files": [
      "jquery.min.js"
    ]
  }
]
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was following along in a Pro ASP.NET Core MVC 2 book that told me to use Bower which is now obsolete. I searched around for a good while before realizing that you can simply right-click your project and select Add -> Client-Side library. And that uses libman. It's all built in.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, you're going to have a hard time using NuGet to install Bootstrap (or most other JavaScript/CSS frameworks) on a .NET Core project. If you look at the NuGet install it tells you it is incompatible:

[image]

if you must know where local packages dependencies are, they are now in your local profile directory. i.e. `%userprofile%\.nuget\packages\bootstrap\4.0.0\content\Scripts`.

However, I suggest switching to npm, or bower - like in Saineshwar's answer.

Answer (score 4):

We use bootstrap 4 in asp.net core but reference the libraries from "npm" using the "Package Installer" extension and found this to be better than Nuget for Javascript/CSS libraries.

We then use the "Bundler & Minifier" extension to copy the relevant files for distribution (from the npm node_modules folder, which sits outside the project) into wwwroot as we like for development/deployment.

Answer (score 2):

BS4 is now available on [.NET Core 2.2](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/2.2). On the SDK 2.2.105 x64 installer for sure.  I'm running Visual Studio 2017 with it.  So far so good for new web application projects.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use a CDN? Unless you need to edit the code of BS, then you just need to reference the codes in CDN.

See BS 4 CDN Here:

https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_get_started.asp

At the bottom of the page.

Comment: Use of a CDN adds a runtime dependency. So if the CDN goes down, so does your site. It's a security issue since whoever controls the cdn can change popular files and inject script into your site. It's also a privacy issue since the user's browser requests the files from a 3rd party server rather than your own.

Comment: @TxRegex at some stage it was actually recommended that references be to CDN rather than a web app's server; because a user's browser was likely to have already cached a popular library such as Bootstrap while perusing other sites. But whatever...

Answer (score 0):

Use nmp configuration file (add it to your web project) then add the needed packages in the same way we did using bower.json and save. Visual studio will download and install it. You'll find the package the under the nmp node  of your project.