# Files Not Appearing In Solution Explorer

Tags: visual-studio-2017, bootstrap-4, nuget

I am using Visual Studio 2017. I created an empty ASP.NET Core Web Application, and then installed the nuget package for Bootstrap through the Nuget Package Manager Console and the bootstrap .css and .js files aren't showing up in the solution explorer. Is this a bug or is there more to using nuget?

Comment: Static files goes under `wwwroot` folder, is this where you are looking at?

Comment: Yes and they aren't showing up.

Comment: Any update for this issue? Have you resolved this issue? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Comment: I guess it's resolved. It looks like I can't use nuget for css and js libraries. Instead of going the npm way I think i'll just get the css and js files i need from bootstrap and jquery's websites and add them manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the bootstrap .css and .js files aren't showing up in the solution explorer. Is this a bug or is there more to using nuget?

That because **the usage of NuGet for css/javascript libraries is discouraged**. You should use the `npm` (Node Package Manager) to add the JavaScript libraries instead of using NuGet. The newer project file formats, `PackageReferences`, only supports files that are in a `contentFiles` directory inside the NuGet package.

To use the package `Bootstrap` to the .net core project, you need to select your `ASP.NET Core Web Application` and add a new file to the project root. While in the template manager (`Add`->`New Item`...), search for "`npm Configuration file`":

Then edit the file and add your dependency, i.e.

package.json (npm) or bower.json:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "Bootstrap": "4.1.3"
  }
```

Note: Once you save, the file will be downloaded in a directory named "node_modules`. This alone won't be enough, as the required files **need to be copied over to wwwroot folder**, where they can be accessed when the application runs.

For the detailed info, see [NPM, BOWER, NUGET, GULP – The Four Horsemen of ASP.NET CORE Apps](http://fiyazhasan.me/npm-bower-nuget-gulp-the-four-horsemen-of-asp-net-core-apps/) and [ASP.NET Core 2.0 and the End of Bower](https://wildermuth.com/2017/11/19/ASP-NET-Core-2-0-and-the-End-of-Bower).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Content in the NuGet file that gets put into your project is only supported with packages.config, which is not supported in .NET Core. PackageReferences do not support getting content from the package.

I'm not 100% sure, but I think the ASP.NET team's recommendation is to use the preferred distribution method of the content you want to use. I haven't kept up with web development trends, but a few years ago web content like bootstrap were distributed with npm, so that's my recommendation for you. Creating a new Angular JS app with Microsoft's new web app template includes a npm package.json, so I think using npm is a safe bet.

Comment: you question is effectively a duplicate of this one, which has a great answer, much better than mine: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48481003/how-to-use-bootstrap-4-in-asp-net-core