# TinyMCE not installing the default scripts

Tags: asp.net-core, model-view-controller, tinymce

I have created a asp.net core 2.2 web app and I want to integrate TinyMCE in it. I found out that you can download it as a nuget package but when I installed it, the package did not come with the TinyMCE js template folder(It just said that the package was installed and that's it). How can I install TinyMCE properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NuGet does not support copying content files to your project directory any more. This was changed when `PackageReference` was introduced which is the new default and only supported way to include package references in .NET Core projects.

So while TinyMCE still updates the NuGet package, you will only be able to consume it properly in classic non-Core ASP.NET MVC projects on the .NET Framework.

If you want to use TinyMCE in ASP.NET Core, you should look [at other mechanisms](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48481003/216074) to include JavaScript dependencies in your application.

When you take a look at TinyMCE’s [“Get TinyMCE” page](https://www.tiny.cloud/get-tiny/), you will see a few options. If you already have some npm-based deployment set up, then you should probably [get it from npm](https://www.tiny.cloud/get-tiny/package-managers/). Otherwise, you can also just [download a static release](https://www.tiny.cloud/get-tiny/downloads/) and copy it into your `wwwroot` directory. This would actuallly have the same effect as using the NuGet package (if that worked).