# How to install and use the latest Bootstrap in an MVC5 project?

Tags: visual-studio, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-core, nuget

I'm trying to use Bootstrap in my ASP.NET MVC5 project (I'd like to use .NET 5, but Visual Basic is not fully supported yet.)

I installed the latest NuGet package, but no folders/files were added to my project—only the package itself under the References node.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48487588) extensive answer, but it's somewhat dated and it addresses a project architecture of ASP.NET Core. I added the suggested `Package.json` file, but no folder `node_modules` was added anywhere in my project.

How do I get started using the Bootstrap NuGet package in my MVC5 project?

**--EDIT--**

I'm using `PackageReference`, not `Packages.config`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For Bootstrap is a **client-side** library,If you download by Nuget Package Manager, you can find it in the `%UserProfile%\.nuget\packages` directory. You could copy and paste it to your project.

Actually I suggest you could use **LibMan** for client-side library.

Here is the steps you could follow:

1. Create the folder `wwwroot/lib`;
2. In Solution Explorer, right-click the project folder in which the files should be added. Choose Add > Client-Side Library.
3. Search for `bootstrap@5.0.2` like below:

   [image]
4. Click the Install button to download the files.

**Reference:**

[Use LibMan with ASP.NET Core in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/libman/libman-vs?view=aspnetcore-2.1#use-the-add-client-side-library-dialog)

**Note:**

The js and css are in `wwwroot/bootstrap/dist/`.

Comment: Very good, thank you. That works. A clarification: when you point out the `dist` subfolder, are you saying that those are the only files I'll need. If its two sibling folders (`js` and `scss`) aren't necessary, I'd like to skip them to reduce project bloat.

Comment: Hi @InteXX, js and scss contains other plugin which is in bootstrap. If you do not want these plugin, you could check the step 3 to choose specific files(see the picture).

Comment: I see that this creates a ```libman.json``` file in my project. When a new nuget version will be released, do I just need to update the version in that file, or do I need to delete the current ```wwwroot/lib/bootstrap``` folder and re-create it with ```Add > Client-Side Library```?

Comment: Hi @demonicdaron, Yes, just update the version in libman.json.