# when i publish asp.net core 3.1 css and boostrap code not worikng

Tags: css, asp.net-core, bootstrap-4, host

when i publish my project to host the css and boostrap codes not working
in local host is working  but in host not

Error
[image]

css and js links

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is the browser you  are using?If you open it in another browser,will you get the error?

Comment: thank you for responce yes i used another browser and i get same error

Answer (score 0):

Usually when we encounter a `404` error, it is because the resource is not found.

## Troubleshooting Steps

**1. Follow the steps like my picture to get the error path.**

[image]

**2. Try to find the file in your root path of webapp. If you can find it, try to access it by broswer.**

[image]

*3. If not, try to cpoy the file from project, and paste it under wwwroot path. After deployed, the structure of folder should like below.*

[image]

[image]

*4. If your file exist, you can access it. So you just need to modify your path in your code.*

**For more details, you can refer this post.**

[How to use Bootstrap 4 in ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48481003/how-to-use-bootstrap-4-in-asp-net-core)